# multiple options or dragging between bags on dragula drag and drop angular 1.*

Tags: drag-and-drop, dragula, angular-dragula

I need two different bags or containers in the same bag.
The left container needs to be a nest-able list, the right container needs to be a sort-able list that can clone objects into the left container.

So I need the ability to either drag between bags or, set up different option sets in containers in the same bag. Is this possible in Dragula?